# How to Pass and Read param in top bar nested navigators?

Tags: reactjs, navigation, expo, react-native

```
const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const TopNavigator = () => {
  return (
      <TopTab.Navigator>
        <TopTab.Screen name="profile" component={profile} />
        <TopTab.Screen name="setting" component={setting} />
      </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
}
const MainMenuStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();

export const MainMenuNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <MainMenuStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavOptions}>
      <MainMenuStackNavigator.Screen name="home" component={homeScreen}/>
      <MainMenuStackNavigator.Screen name="tab" component={TopNavigator }/>
    </MainMenuStackNavigator.Navigator>
  );
};


function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Top Navigator Screen"
        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate({name: "tab",params:{data: "Testing"}});}}
      />;
    </View>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        < MainMenuNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Need to pass Data from 'home' screen to both 'Profile' and 'Setting' screen
i know how pass data from home screen to any one of those screen,

```
props.navigation.navigate(tab, {
        screen: "profile",
        params: { data: 'testing'}
});
```

**but here my question is ' how to send data to both screens(profile and setting)?**